# Firebase functions warning - consistent return

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am deploying database functions to google cloud functions using firebase-functions. I have seen some warnings lately.

> 98:29  warning  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow
>   function  consistent-return

My code

```
exports.onUserUpdate = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.database
.ref('users/{userId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const userId = context.params.userId
  const userData = change.after.val()
  const time = (userData.createdAt) ? userData.createdAt : Date.now().valueOf()
  const user = (context.auth) ? context.auth.uid : 'Firebase console'

  const before = change.before.val()
  const after = change.after.val()

  //Prevent eternal loop!
  if(_.isEqual(before, after)){
    console.log("No change, exiting")
    return null
  }

  const dbRef = change.after.ref
  const dbRoot = dbRef.root

  //Destructure user data
  const {
    alias = '',
    createdAt = moment().valueOf(),
    displayName = '',
    name = '',
    email = '',
    profilePhotoUrl = '',
  } = userData

  //Compose payload
  const payload = {
    dbRoot,
    time,
    user,
    createdAt,
    userId,
    name,
    displayName,
    alias,
    email
  }

  //Collect and run all promises to execute
  const updates = getUpdateUserInDatabaseFunctionArray(payload) 
  //The functions fetched above log out "updateUserFunction 1/2/3"
  let userUpdatePromises = updates.concat([writeUserHistory(payload)])
  Promise.all(userUpdatePromises)
  .then(()=>{
    return true
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    console.log("onUserUpdate error", err)
    return false
  })

  //return true <-- Line 98
  //This line is not needed since I return true or false after promise completion?
}
```

Function getUpdateUserInDatabaseFunctionArray()

```
function getUpdateUserInDatabaseFunctionArray({dbRoot, userId, name, displayName, alias, email}){
  const updateContacts = 
  dbRoot.child('contacts')
  .orderByKey()
  .equalTo(userId)
  .once('value', (contactSnapshot) => {
    console.log('updateUserFunction 1')
    //...
  })

  const updateMessages = dbRoot.child('messages')
  .orderByChild('senderId')
  .equalTo(userId)
  .once('value', (contactSnapshot) => {
    console.log('updateUserFunction 2')
    //...
  })

  const updateAlerts = dbRoot.child('alerts')
  .orderByChild('uid')
  .equalTo(userId)
  .once('value', (contactSnapshot) => {
    console.log('updateUserFunction 1')
    //...
  })

  return [
    updateContacts,
    updateInvitations,
    updateNotificationsinvitations
  ]
}
```

If line 98 is included I do not get the warning - but that also means the function does not execute correctly.

The log output shows that the execution has finished although the promises has not yet resolved. As expected. The output will be along the lines of:

```
 "Function execution started"
```

> "writeUserHistory historyObject { time: 1538330532000, user: 'SYSTEM'}"
>   "Function execution took 256 ms, finished with status: 'ok'"
>   "updateUserFunction 1"
>   "updateUserFunction 2"
>   "updateUserFunction 3"

If I ommit line 98 I get the above warning. 
How can I avoid the warning while ommiting line 98?

Comment: Please edit the question to show all relevant code.  This snippet isn't enough to understand what all is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're obliged to return a promise from your function that resolves after all the async work is complete.  This signals to Cloud Functions when it's safe to clean up everything from that invocation.  It's not sufficient to just call then and catch on each promise, as those callbacks are also asynchronous like the original function that returned the promise.

So, you'll need to:

```
return Promise.all(userUpdatePromises)
...
```